# How create an object for class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, xunit

i am try to pass some values to httpserver.
this is my class

```
public interface ICommandRestClient
{
    IRestResult Send(IMessageEnvelope envelope);
}
public class CommandRestClient : ICommandRestClient
{
    private readonly string _serverAddress;

    /// <summary>
    /// Use to configure server address
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverAddress">Configured serveraddress</param>
    public CommandRestClient(string serverAddress)
    {
        _serverAddress = serverAddress;
    }

    public IRestResult Send(IMessageEnvelope envelope)
    {
    //do 
    }
}
```

and its working. now i am try to write some Xunit test class for `Send` method. for that i need to create an Object to access `CommandRestClient` class. but i did not have `serverAddress` value. i want to create an object for  `CommandRestClient` class by hardcore the address values or without passing `serverAddress`. please help me 
thank you.

Comment: Make an appropriate value up (single or from a factory) for whatever you're testing on the CommandRestClient implementation. If testing something that *uses* an ICommandRestClient, then you may be able to mock that (and forget about serverAddress entirely).

Comment: Your subject does not reflect your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you will create a xunit class called CommandRestClientTest to test CommandRestClient. You can hardcode a ServerAddress constant in that class to hardcode the serverAddress and pass it to every CommandRestClient instance you create in that xunit class.

Bear in mind that if you are actually testing a send method to somewhere that is an integration test. To be a pure unit test you would mock external interaction and only test business logic in CommandRestClient

In Unit you will typically put this in the initialization marked as [Setup] but xunit encourages you to create the object in every method.

sample code(haven't compiled it)

```
public class CommandRestClientTest
{
    const string testServerAddress = "localhost:8080";

    [Fact]
    public void TestSomeMethod()
    {
        CommandRestClient commandRestClient = new CommandRestClient(testServerAddress);

        //test, assert etc
    }
}
```

Comment: is it somethings like this ?  private readonly CommandRestClient _commandRestClient = new CommandRestClient("http://localhost:8088/");